# PowerShell add a function to a custom object

Tags: powershell, methods

I try to add an existing function as a method to a new created object.
Writing an inline function works:

```
$myObject | Add-Member ScriptMethod -name Calc -value{param([int]$a,[int]$b;$a+$b}
```

Having a function:

```
function get-Calc{param([int]$a,[int]$b) $a +$b}
```

this doesn't work:

```
$myObject | Add-Member ScriptMethod -name Calc -value(get-Calc)
```

Comment: What's the point of adding it as a method on a specific object if the function doesn't use the object in any way?

Comment: but I like to use this method, like that: $myObject.Calc(2,3)

Comment: I get that, I just don't understand why :) Normally you'd attach code that references the object itself, eg.: `$myObject = [pscustomobject]@{ MyValue = 123 } |Add-Member -Name Times -Value {param([int]$X) return $this.MyValue * $X} -PassThru -MemberType ScriptMethod`, which would then make `$myObject.Times(2)` evaluate to `246`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defined functions are stored in the special `function:\` drive.

To reference a function definition using variable syntax:

```
$myObject | Add-Member ScriptMethod -name Calc -Value ${function:get-Calc}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also do it passing a script block as `-Value`, see the **Constructor** for [PSScriptMethod Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psscriptmethod?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#constructors).

```
function Get-Calc { param([int] $a, [int] $b) $a + $b }

$myObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    A = 1
    B = 2
}

# If you're referencing the existing Properties of the Object:
$myObject | Add-Member ScriptMethod -Name MyMethod1 -Value {
    Get-Calc $this.A $this.B
}

# If you want the Instance Method to reference the arguments being passed:
$myObject | Add-Member ScriptMethod -Name MyMethod2 -Value {
    param([int] $a, [int] $b)

    Get-Calc $a $b
}

# This is another alternative as the one above:
$myObject.PSObject.Methods.Add(
    [psscriptmethod]::new(
        'MyMethod3', {
            param([int] $a, [int] $b)

            Get-Calc $a $b
        }
    )
)

$myObject.MyMethod1()
$myObject.MyMethod2(1, 2)
$myObject.MyMethod3(3, 4)
```

**Note:** All examples in this answer require that the function `Get-Calc` is defined in the parent scope and will fail as soon as the definition for the function has changed. Instead you should pass in the definition as a [Script Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2) as [Mathias's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71020740/15339544) is showing.

Comment: @zett42 It was meant to show the alternative to `Add-Member`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your example that do not work.

- You are not passing `Get-Calc` as a scriptblock (The expected value for a scriptmethod is a scriptblock)
- You are not passing your expected parameters

Instead of

```
$myObject | Add-Member ScriptMethod -name Calc -value(get-Calc)
```

Do this:

```
$myObject | Add-Member ScriptMethod -name Calc3 -value {param([int]$a,[int]$b) get-Calc -a $a -b $b}
```